# Headphones not detected and sound playing from both speakers and headphones

Tags: 20.04, sound, 22.04, hp

I just bought an HP G9 with and Intel I5-1235U processor and installed Ubuntu 22 LTS. It seems that the audio jack cannot be detected but when plugged in, sound actually plays from both the headphones and the speakers. Tried also with Ubuntu 20 LTS but same thing continues. What should I do in order to fix this?

Update: The output of `hdajacksensetest` is the same either the headphones are connected or not.

Pin 0x19 (Black Mic, Left side): present = No
Pin 0x21 (Black Headphone, Left side): present = No

Comment: I have the same problem with the same notebook, HP 250 G9, in Kubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Usually in a situation like this, the first thing we usually do is install the Pulse Audio Volume Control app (this is not the same as the default volume control). So run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

After installation, run the command `pavucontrol` or search for "pulse audio volume control" in your installed apps and open the app. From here, there will be a few tabs with more detailed selections for your devices like your headphones on each tab and you should also have dropdown selection menus for input/output devices as well.

Comment: I have already done this. The problem is that on Output Devices tab the "sof-hda-dap Speaker + Headphones" port option always shows Headphones as unplugged even if they are actually plugged in.

Comment: @user7375077 you're right! I have the same issue! But i can hear the headphone together the notebook speaker, I need to select manually "only headphone".